# How to combine 2 arrays so that each of them has elements from the other for O (n) complexity?

Tags: javascript

How to combine 2 arrays so that each of them has elements from the other for O (n) complexity?
I need that each object contain 1 element from another array, so we have 4 pair

```
let arr = [1,2]
let arr2 = ['first','second']
```

**my solution with nested loops** O(n^2)

```
const result = [];
for (let coachId of arr) {
  for (let managerId of arr2)
    result.push({ id1: coachId, id2: managerId });
}
```

**expected result**

```
[{id1: 1, id2: 'first'}, {id1: 1, id2: 'second'}, {id1: 2, id2: 'first'}, {id1: 2, id2: 'second'}]
```

Comment: What is `n`? The total number of elements in all arrays? Is the number of arrays constant 2? Is the size of both arrays always equal?

Comment: yes, how we can do this task without nested loops

Comment: The result has `arr.length * arr2.length` elements. It's the Cartesian product. You can't achieve this with `O(n)` operations.

Comment: In theory you could use a proxy and make array indexes calculated.  Not sure it would help with Time Complexity though.. :)  But would get rid of the double loop.  mmm, actually you could do this without the double loop without the proxy too.  Hint:  use div & modulus..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out this won't reduce the time complexity of the full result, but you can use div & modulus to build up the result, this then avoids the double loop, and then you could use to reduce the time complexity of partial results, eg. paging data etc..

Out of curiosity did a quick benchmark doing this, and it is actually twice as fast too.  But as pointed out in comments, it's more than likely the `for of` that's slows things down in your example, I assume there is a bit of overhead in JS creating the iterator for the array.

```js
let arr = [1,2]
let arr2 = ['first','second']

const len = arr.length * arr2.length;
const result = new Array(len);
for (let p = 0; p < len; p += 1) {
  result[p] = {
    id1: arr[p / arr.length | 0],
    id2: arr2[p % arr.length]
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: _"Not sure of the Time Complexity of doing this"_ It still has the same time complexity O(n1 * n2).

Comment: @jabaa  Good point, I've updated to explain things a bit clearer.

Comment: I suspect that the `for of` loop is the culprit. With plain old indexed loops, two nested ones doing half each, or a single one doing everything should not make any measurable difference.

Comment: @Tomalak  Yes, that would make sense, updated answer to point this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to alter the shape of the array

```js
let arr = [1,2]
let arr2 = ['first','second']

const result = arr.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  const obj = arr2.map(item => {
    return {id1: current, id2: item};
  });
  return accumulator.concat(obj);
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Here is the process you start with performing a loop through the first array `arr` and for each item in that array you loop through each item in the second array `arr2` and create an object with value from both Arrays

Comment: You should mention the time complexity O(n1 * n2) in your answer, because this seems to be an important point in the question.

Answer (score -5):

Here is what you could do in O(n) complexity, following would also handle case if your arrays aren't equal:

```
let arr = [1,2];
let arr2 = ['first','second','three'];
var res = [];
var maxLen = arr.length > arr2.length ? arr.length : arr2.length;
var i1=0;
var i2=0;
for(var i=0;i<maxLen;i++)
{
  if(arr[i1])
  {
    res.push(arr[i1]);
    i1++;
  }
  if(arr2[i2])
  {
    res.push(arr2[i2]);
    i2++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Admittedly, the question was poorly worded, but based on the example provided, this is not what was asked for.